# Fatal error: Call to a member function set_charset()

Tags: php, sql, database, cpanel, web-hosting

I am using Cpanel to develop my application. It gives the error

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function set_charset() on a non-object in /home/restaur  /public_html/restaurant/includes/connect_database.php on line 3
```

when I access to "www.yyyyy.com/filename/"

And here is my connect_database script

```
<?php 
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/YOUR_FOLDER/variables/variables.php'); 
$connect->set_charset('utf8');  
?>
```

my close_database script

```
<?php
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/YOUR_FOLDER/variables/variables.php');
$connect->close();
?>
```

my variable script

```
<?php
// database configuration
$host ="db_host_name";
$user ="db_username";
$pass ="db_pasword";
$database = "database_name";
$connect = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass,$database) or die("Error :       ".mysql_error());?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it should be like

```
$host ="db_host_name";
$user ="db_username";
$pass ="db_pasword";
$database = "database_name";

// variables.php
$connect = new mysqli($host, $user, $pass, $database);

/* check connection */
if ($connect->connect_errno) {
    printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $connect->connect_error);
    exit();
}
```

Now in `connect_database.php`

```
// Make sure your included path is correct
include($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'].'/YOUR_FOLDER/variables/variables.php'); 
global $connect;

$connect->set_charset('utf8');
```

this will help you to know more in depth [global](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php)

Comment: it got an error like this if I change the php

    Fatal error: Call to a member function set_charset() on a   non-object in /home/restaur/public_html/restaurant/includes/connect_database.php on line 10

Comment: Why do you use `global` here ? The `$connect` is not under any function right ?

Comment: @ShankarDamodaran according to OP `my variable script` he is connection his database in `variables.php` file and using that connection in `connect_database.php` file that's why i used `global` to access the object of connection.

Comment: what is the meaning about world? what should I enter in this case ?

Comment: @user3423149 its a Database name :), i thought you understand. I think now its clear view for you.

Answer (score 0):

I was having this exact issue, i was having encoding problems but adding

```
$connect->set_charset('utf8');
```

(my variable was actually `$conn->set_charset('utf8');`) just after

```
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
```

and it worked beautifully.